# Why are my AIR apps packaged on linux being corrupt when used on the mac?

Tags: linux, air

I have a need to generate my air app online on my linux webserver. I create a signature and package the app up with adt and then download it to my desktop mac and try and install it, it says the package is corrupt and to get another copy. But when I compile it on the mac (using the exact same commands to adt) it installs and runs fine.

Why is packaging using the linux SDK creating corrupt .air files ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the adt binary doesn't work 100% in Linux.